# HttpServletResponse.setStatus() works once, does nothing when called again - change between Java 8/Tomcat 9.0.0 and Java 10/Tomcat 9.0.8?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have a Java servlet running under Tomcat 9 which, as part of the normal flow, calls `HttpServletResponse#setStatus()` a few times.

When running on Tomcat 9.0.0.M26 with Java 8 (1.8.0u144, reported by Tomcat as `1.8.0_144-b01`), this works fine.

When running on Tomcat 9.0.8.0 with Java 10.0.1 (reported by Tomcat as `10.0.1+10`), it appears that calling setStatus() on the response object only actually causes the response status to be set *once*, after which the HTTP status can no longer be changed. It does however appear that other headers, sent to the client via HttpServletResponse#setHeader(), are unaffected by this; setHeader() successfully adds headers even after setStatus() no longer does anything. There is no intermediary output data being sent that could cause the HTTP header to be terminated.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
package org.example;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/HttpResponseStatusTestServlet")
public class HttpResponseStatusTestServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.getWriter().append("Testing ");
        response.setStatus(505);
        response.setStatus(506);
        response.getWriter()
            .append("Served at: ")
            .append(request.getContextPath())
            .append(" with: ")
            .append(Integer.toString(response.getStatus()));
    }
}
```

When calling this servlet, I expect to get back the string `Testing Served at: ... with: 506` because the last HTTP status set before the `getStatus()` call is `506`. The HTTP status code returned to the client should likewise be `506`.

However, what I do end up getting is `Testing Served at: ... with: 505` and a `505` HTTP status. It's like the second setStatus() call isn't even there.

The result is the same (except for the existence of `Testing` at the beginning of the output) whether or not the `response.getWriter().append("Testing ");` before the setStatus() call is included, so it doesn't appear to be about an early-termination HTTP response header.

There is no indication visible anywhere that I can see that the second setStatus() call failed in any way, or even that it was ever there; it appears that anywhere beyond the first call to setStatus(), calling setStatus() on the response object does absolutely nothing at all.

The return value of `response.isCommitted()` is `false` throughout the above servlet on the problematic server: after the `getWriter().append("Testing ");` call, after the `setStatus(505)` call, and after the `setStatus(506)` call.

I realize that calling setStatus() multiple times for the same request might be slightly unorthodox, but:

- Is this really not supposed to work with Tomcat 9.0.8 and Java 10, given that it worked perfectly with Tomcat 9.0.0 and Java 8?
- What would be an equivalent that does work with the more recent versions?

Using a common web search engine left me none the wiser about what's going on, and the documentation I was able to find does not indicate that setStatus() can only be called once, nor that it can be called multiple times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `setStatus()` multiple times isn't forbidden, and if you look at Tomcat internals you'll see that there are places where the status can be changed multiple times (and of course if it were forbidden, you'd get an exception).

This was caused by a [regression bug](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/commit/2b239e1ea0f3f8b5cdf01062a106ade9465756ec) fixed in Tomcat 9.0.10 and 9.0.9, but not 9.0.8 (didn't look where the bug was introduced, possibly in 9.0.8).

Essentially trying to change the status code if it was already set to a value over 399 didn't have any effect because of

```
if (this.status > 399) {
    // Don't overwrite first recorded error status
    return;
}
```

Comment: The problematic code was introduced on [Feb 8, 2018](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/commit/8f85c08925bc3dc39210f24b484aab30b4ed2b93#diff-95185e588de3604778aaae00c0afdf10), then removed on [Apr 30](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/commit/2b239e1ea0f3f8b5cdf01062a106ade9465756ec#diff-95185e588de3604778aaae00c0afdf10). Looking at the release [tags](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/tags), 9.0.5 was taken on Feb 6 and 9.0.6 on Mar 5. So in the 9.x series, this should be a problem in 9.0.6 (Mar 5), 9.0.7 (Apr 3) and 9.0.8 (Apr 27), but not 9.0.5 (Feb 6) or older, or 9.0.9 (Jun 20) and newer.

Comment: Adding to the above comment, I can confirm that (1) everything worked as expected when I used status codes in the 2xx range instead of status codes in the 5xx range, and (2) the problem no longer existed when I upgraded to Tomcat 9.0.10. This applies to both the MWE in the question as well as the actual application.