# Boolean.TRUE == someMethod(), where return type is Boolean for someMethod() and it returns a literal true

Tags: java, hibernate, boolean, boolean-expression

Please have a look at the below program :-

```
class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Boolean.TRUE == new Main().getBoolean());
  }

  public Boolean getBoolean() {
    return true;
  }
}
```

If I check the Java Mnemonics for this, I get :-

```
Compiled from "Main.java"
class com.testing.Main {
  com.testing.Main();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       3: getstatic     #3                  // Field java/lang/Boolean.TRUE:Ljava/lang/Boolean;
       6: new           #4                  // class com/testing/Main
       9: dup
      10: invokespecial #5                  // Method "<init>":()V
      13: invokevirtual #6                  // Method getBoolean:()Ljava/lang/Boolean;
      16: if_acmpne     23
      19: iconst_1
      20: goto          24
      23: iconst_0
      24: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Z)V
      27: return

  public java.lang.Boolean getBoolean();
    Code:
       0: iconst_1
       1: invokestatic  #8                  // Method java/lang/Boolean.valueOf:(Z)Ljava/lang/Boolean;
       4: areturn
}
```

Therefore, in Java Mnemonics :
for line no. 0 and 1 of the last method i.e. `getBoolean() method`, 
we see auto-boxing happening, i.e. `iconst_1` i.e. `int 1` (which means 'true' here) (in line 0) is passed to  `Boolean.valueOf()` method (in line 1).
And `Boolean.valueOf(boolean b)` method in `Java.Lang`, returns a constant `Boolean.TRUE` or `Boolean.FALSE`.

Therefore, the `==` check should always work fine, in the program `main` method, 
or in the Java Mnemonics : Line no 16.
But in some environments, I see this returning false.
How is it possible?

> Edit :  Here, in my case, to be precise : Hibernate fetches a BIT from
>   the DB and sets into a Boolean field. This Boolean field has a getter,
>   which is the `getBoolean()` in my above program.

Comment: What kind of environment is your code running in? Are multiple classloaders involved?

Comment: According to javadoc `Boolean.valueOf()` returns `Boolean.TRUE` or `Boolean.FALSE`. So this resulting in `false` can not happen, unless you have a bug in your jvm implementation or a really broken classloader hierachy. (It is more likely that the `Boolean` giving you `false` was just created with `new Boolean(boolean)`)

Comment: @k5_ I'd be more concerned that somehow the boolean values are not interned somehow, so object comparison takes over.

Comment: To add, the boolean i.e. being fetched from the method, is being fetched, from a BIT column in a Table in MySQL.
The Java type for the particular SQL Type BIT is java.lang.Boolean.
Hibernate is fetching this data.

Comment: Can there be any way, where Hibernate is playing with this?

Comment: Then it **could** be a Hibernate bug (i.e. Hibernate not using the constants like @k5_ said), but you'd be better off not using `==` to compare objects in the first place.

Comment: Would love to have a more specific answer, with some proof :)
I hope, hibernate doesn't do a new Boolean(value), with the bit value it gets out of the DB.

Comment: @k5_ Its as simple as it sounds. And the results are as complex as it looks.

Comment: While I do [dig into the source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51423223/httpservletresponse-setstatus-works-once-does-nothing-when-called-again-cha) every now and then, I'm not going to dig into Hibernate. Especially since you don't even mention the version.

Comment: Oops, my bad, version for Hibernate : 4.3.1.Final

Comment: @AayushShrivastava for your specific example it is safe to use the identity operator. For cases where you dont know exactly where the `Boolean` came from use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22491853/how-to-compare-boolean

Comment: @k5_ Thanks for sharing the URL. I get your point, that equals check should be the way to go for this kinda check. But I'm trying to understand, how can it ever fail here, with a DB fetch of BIT using hibernate, and a `Boolean` getter. Nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing the obvious here, this is entirely possible and depends on what `getBoolean` returns:

```
public static Boolean getBoolean() {
    return new Boolean(true);
}

Boolean aha = Boolean.TRUE;
Boolean aha2 = getBoolean();

System.out.println(aha == aha2); // false
```

But than `Boolean::equals` must be used when comparing `Boolean`s, obviously.

Comment: Yeah, correct a new Boolean(boolean value) would make it false. And that is the only case I can assume, this can happen.
But does, hibernate fetch the BIT from the DB, and return a new Boolean(bitValue)?

Comment: @AayushShrivastava why don't you find out, post an answer, and if it does (and it hasn't been fixed in a later version) report a bug to Hibernate developers.

Comment: Of course, in case of `Boolean.TRUE == getBoolean()`, you don’t need to use `equals`, you can simply use `true == getBoolean()`, or even better, `getBoolean()` instead.